# if dsum is blank then insert 0

Tags: forms, textbox, ms-access-2010

I am trying to sum text boxes in a form within access 2010.

Within the text boxes I am summing there is the dsum function. The query is time dependent and will be updated throughout the day. This causes some boxes to be empty at points throughout the day.
I need to input a zero so I can sum the total in another box but I am having trouble.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
= IID(Dsum("[field_name]", "[table_name]", "[time]='08'") = '', 0, _ 
      Dsum("[field_name]", "[table_name]", "[time]='08'"))
```

I have tried it with single and double quotes around the zero and single and double quotes around the 'If blank' may be I haven't got the right permutation? Please help its driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

DSum returns a Null, if the condition is not met. So try wrapping it in Nz(). Something like,

```
= Nz(Dsum("[field_name]","[table_name]","[time]='08'"), 0)
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Many thanks I forgot about it being null as opposed to blank

Comment: Glad to help. Please feel free to mark it as answer, so it might help others in need. :) Good Luck